# Prior art for square-root-based EC decompression formula?

Tags: elliptic-curves, math-history

In October 2021, Helder Eijis published [this formula](https://github.com/Legrandin/pycryptodome/blob/d8edf1a6a70d3a65dcda18ee24d96161525f2825/lib/Crypto/PublicKey/ECC.py#L878) for recovering the $y$-coordinate of an elliptic curve point from only the $x$-coordinate, the parity of the $y$-coordinate, and the curve's $b$-value, when the curve and co-ordinates are in the short Weierstrass representation (an operation generally needed when [parsing compressed encodings](https://www.secg.org/sec1-v2.pdf#page=18) of points on NIST curves):

$${y_P}'=\sqrt{{x_P}^3-3x_P+b_E}\\y_P={y_P}'\cdot {-1}^{{y_P}'+\tilde{y}_P}$$

Obviously, this is far easier to use in programming contexts than Nigel Smart's didactic ["half-trace" process](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/21080/8287). But was it original? It was introduced without citation, only with the comment “ECC keys can be exported/imported in the SEC1 *[sic]* format”.

Is there prior art here, or was that formula invented for the first time in the development of that library?